# Change only one column delimiter PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, hive, pyspark, rdd

> a = ['0,Italy,**"Aromas include tropical fruit, broom, brimstone and dried herb. The palate isnt overly expressive, offering unripened apple, citrus and dried sage alongside brisk acidity."**,Vulkà Bianco,87,,Sicily & Sardinia,Etna,,Kerin O’Keefe,@kerinokeefe,Nicosia 2013 Vulkà Bianco  (Etna),White Blend,Nicosia']

I have this list, and I want to change ONLY the bold string delimiter from "," to "#" for example.

Comment: What should your output be?

Comment: Is there a reason you've tagged this with `pyspark` and rdd?

Comment: basicly I have an CSV file, then I have to create an HIVE table in HDFS. But since the DESCRIPTION has commas in it, the delimiter messes everything up. So a collegue told me I needed to change it in Python, using RDD's

Comment: it would be helpful if you could give an example of such an RDD (you can create one in the `pyspark` shell using a `spark` context with a few rows, and I could update my answer with some better example

Answer (score 1):

This gets you what you want given the input:

```
a[0].split('"')[1].replace(",", "#")
```

But something tells me that's not too useful/general.

But anyway a solution to this kind of problem will probably involve these two string/list methods: `split` and `replace`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

### update

So if you need to use a spark RDD, you can first create the RDD using the list of strings (not yet a csv)

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize(a)
>>> rdd.take(1)
['0,Italy,"Aromas include tropical fruit, broom, brimstone and dried herb. The palate isnt overly expressive, offering unripened apple, citrus and dried sage alongside brisk acidity.",Vulk\xc3\xa0 Bianco,87,,Sicily & Sardinia,Etna,,Kerin O\xe2\x80\x99Keefe,@kerinokeefe,Nicosia 2013 Vulk\xc3\xa0 Bianco (Etna),White Blend,Nicosia']
>>> processed_rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: row.split('"')[0] + row.split('"')[1].replace(",", "#") + row.split('"')[2])
>>> processed_rdd.take(1)
['0,Italy,Aromas include tropical fruit# broom# brimstone and dried herb. The palate isnt overly expressive# offering unripened apple# citrus and dried sage alongside brisk acidity.,Vulk\xc3\xa0 Bianco,87,,Sicily & Sardinia,Etna,,Kerin O\xe2\x80\x99Keefe,@kerinokeefe,Nicosia 2013 Vulk\xc3\xa0 Bianco (Etna),White Blend,Nicosia']
```

There are **several assumptions** I'm making, because you only supplied one example row.

These assumptions are about the existence of this double quoted string `" "`, which is the column with commas needing replacing.

Further, I'm assuming there are no `"` in any of the other columns.

I'm also assuming this column doesn't need those `"` in it after it is processed.

### explanation

the `rdd` method `map` will map a function onto each row in an RDD, and the lambda that the `map` takes returns the new row. So here I'm mapping this replacing chain of commands to each row in the RDD (and then in the example, I `take` one)

Comment: That is just a row from 50 from a CSV file. I just needed some ideas on how to do it, so I can replicate it to the rest of the file.

Thanks for the help btw !

Comment: I hope this is a better solution then :), I've updated it with some spark example